# Similar tool like inotify for kernel version 2.6.9 (or lower)

Tags: c++, linux, monitoring, inotify

I have to write application in c++ (linux environment) which monitors the file changes and hold the process till file writing is not closed. I have looked and installed inotify But it did not work as I have kernel version 2.6.9. I can not upgrade kernel version as I am using a remote machine.

Do we have any tool which can be used in c++ (linux machine) with kernel 2.6.9 or lwoer?

Comment: That's a very old kernel version; can you upgrade?

Comment: Is polling an option?

Comment: A quick Google search should take you to [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_alteration_monitor). If that can't be used, see the "See also" section.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain,we use remote machine and we do not acess have permission to upgrade kernel.

Comment: @Polling is an option, our intention is lock the file till process running or check the status of files if they are modifying

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use [`dnotify`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnotify) ?

It is available starting `2.4` kernels and have been obsoleted by `inotify` since `2.6.13` kernels.

`dnotify` is accessible through the `fcntl` API and it is more than likely that it could be available on your current kernel if the `inotify` APIs aren't. [Here](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/filesystems/dnotify.txt) is a doc on how to use it.